# .htaccess rewrite issues with homepage

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ parser.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The issue is that when I try to access my homepage by www.site.com, it rewrites it as well to parser.php, why is this and how do I prevent this?

Comment: It rewrites everything because you're telling it to rewrite everything.  Can you share, specifically, what you want to rewrite, and what you don't?

Comment: I don't want it to rewrite when I visit the homepage, say www.mysite.com.. everything else is fine to be rewritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exempt the root from the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Allow the rewrite to proceed only if the URI does *not* match this pattern
# The pattern used is ^/$ - this will only match the exact string "/" for the root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
# Your existing rule
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ parser.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried this and it still redirects my www.mysite.com to the parser.php

Comment: Huh.  Set a `RewriteLog` and set `RewriteLogLevel 9` and get the output when incorrectly redirects?

Comment: Where do I put this RewriteLog, sorry I never used it before

Comment: In the `<VirtualHost>` block for your site.

Comment: here is the log http://pastie.org/2737100, it's a huge file

Comment: @EquinoX Ahh, `index.php` - that'll do it!  Change the `RewriteCond` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$`